# descubrir modelos loopback js

Tags: nodejs, oracle, loopbackjs

Estoy tratando de descubrir los modelos en una base de datos oracle con loopback como dice la documentación pero no se como generar los modelos .json , saben de algun ejemplo, en la documentación dice que se debe usar con `fs.writeFile()`  pero no se muestra el ejemplo, estoy usando lo siguiente para conectarme

```
var loopback = require('loopback');    
var ds = loopback.createDataSource('oracle', {
   "host": "oracle.local",
    "port": 1521,
    "database": "XE",
    "password": "password",
    "user": "user",
});

function schemaCallback(err, schema) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  console.log(schema)
  }
// Discover and build models from INVENTORY table
ds.discoverAndBuildModels('VISION', {owner:'owner', relations: true, all:true , associations:true}, schemaCallback);
```

Comment: lo genere como me dijiste pero al ejecutar  el código me sale como variable no definida, al hacer pruebas el schema devuelto en el schemaCallback es un objeto con varias tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya verificaste que te puedes conectar a la base y que detecta el modelo correctamente, sigue estos pasos.

1. Al inicio de tu script carga el módulo `fs`
2. Después define la ruta para guardar tu modelo, generalmente es `common/models/modelo.json`
3. A continuación coloca el código que ya tienes
4. Por último, guarda el archivo con el método `fs.writeFile`

> #### Notas
>
> - Es recomendable que coloques el modelo descubierto en una variable.
> - La ruta que coloqué es relativa a la ubicación del script, cámbiala adecuadamente
> - Use la función `JSON.stringifly` para guardar el modelo, verifica el resultado final y si no es correcto o no se ve bien, puedes eliminarla **sin ningún problema**.
> - Verifica el archivo JSON generado y asegúrate que los campos `base` y `plural` estén bien definidos.
> - Verifica que el modelo esté definido en `./server/model-config.json`

Este es el código de ejemplo.

```js
// cargas el módulo fs
const fs = require('fs)

// la ruta donde vas a guardar tu modelo
const archivoModelo = './common/models/vision.json'

// El código de tu conexión
// coloca en una variable el modelo "descubierto"
// p. ej.
// const modeloDescubierto = ds.discoverAndBuildModels('VISION'...

// Guarda la salida en el archivo
fs.writeFile(modeloGenerado, JSON.stringify(modeloDescubierto), (err) => {
  if(err) return console.log(err)
  console.log("El modelo se genero exitosamente")
})
```

Comment: lo genere como me dijiste pero al ejecutar  var modelo = ds.discoverAndBuildModels('VISION', {owner:'owner', relations: true, all:true , associations:true}, schemaCallback);
console.log(modelo);